# Vue3 upgrade - ERROR: [plugin: vite:dep-scan] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: vue.js, vite

I migrated from webpack to vite successfully in a vue2 project and now I am upgrading from vue2 to vue3.

I made it until step 4 in this guide: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html#installation, and now the build process gives me this error.

`ERROR: [plugin: vite:dep-scan] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

It looks like the vite compat builder is not able to find the file `/src/main.js`, because if I rename or even delete the file, the error remains the same.

Did I miss something?

```
✘ [ERROR] [plugin vite:dep-scan] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

    node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:60384:34:
      60384 │     if (importee.length < pattern.length) {
            ╵                                   ^

    at matches (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:60384:35)
    at /home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:60443:58
    at Array.find (<anonymous>)
    at Context.resolveId (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:60443:42)
    at Object.resolveId (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:38837:55)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async resolve (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:39049:26)
    at async /home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:39257:34
    at async callback (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:929:28)
    at async handleRequest (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:709:30)

  This error came from the "onResolve" callback registered here:

    node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:39253:18:
      39253 │             build.onResolve({
            ╵                   ~~~~~~~~~

    at setup (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:39253:19)
    at handlePlugins (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:851:23)
    at Object.buildOrServe (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1145:7)
    at /home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2087:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.build (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2086:14)
    at Object.build (/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1935:51)
    at /home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:38997:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)

  The plugin "vite:dep-scan" was triggered by this import

    html:/home/user/projects/ipfs-search/dweb-search-frontend/index.html:1:7:
      1 │ import "/src/main.js"
        ╵        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:60384:34: ERROR: [plugin: vite:dep-scan] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import path from 'path';
import createVuePlugin from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    createVuePlugin({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          compatConfig: {
            MODE: 2,
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  server: {
    port: 8080,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        vue: '@vue/compat',
      },
      {
        find: '@',
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by Frido Emans answer, I found the issue was using a list into `alias`. I ended up replacing

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
      },
      {
        find: "./runtimeConfig",
        replacement: "./runtimeConfig.browser",
      },
    ]
  },
});
```

by (notice the alias list is gone)

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        "./runtimeConfig": "./runtimeConfig.browser",
        "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url))
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: It did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Well I found an answer; the alias in `vite.config.js`:

```
  {
    vue: '@vue/compat',
  },
```

seemed to cause the error.

Note that this snippet was copied directly from the official vue.js vue3 migration guide. After I removed it, the error disappeared, and more comprehensible errors came, as the ones I expected.